# Is std::bind ignoring superfluous arguments standard-conforming?

Tags: c++, c++11

The functor returned by `std::bind` ignores superfluous arguments [[SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251976/why-do-objects-returned-from-bind-ignore-extra-arguments), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298377/why-doesnt-stdbind-account-for-function-arity), [SO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762844/c-how-to-write-a-stdbind-like-object-that-checks-for-superfulous-parameters)]. A simple example looks as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo(int a) {
  std::cout << "a=" << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  auto f = std::bind(foo, 42);
  f(3141); // a=42
}
```

It is clear that implementing `std::bind` in this way is easier [[SO1a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252595/)]. Is, however, this  ignoring of superfluous arguments standardized or undefined behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), the superfluous arguments will be discarded.

> If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to g() are not matched by any placeholders stored in g, the unused arguments are evaluated and discarded.